# How to pass Data Studio Controls to BigQuery custom query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have the Data Studio Report in which I have Date and Task Controls.

[image]

I am using custom BigQuery and have already set the date Control via `date between @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE` but I also need to set Task in the custom query.

[image]

Note: I cannot use the parameter like Task = @Task because Task is a Control while adding parameter(@Task) is a completely different thing.

Update : The task is not a first-level filter. Somehow I need it to pass it in the subquery. I can pass the date in subquery via @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE but cannot do the same with Task.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a specific requirement, your setup as it is should work. I'm assuming `Task` is a field in your data. When the report viewer picks one or more values from the `Task` filter control, Data Studio will send the query to BigQuery with appropriate filter clause. You can confirm this by looking at the billing project's query history in BigQuery.

Edit(since OP has a specific requirement to add the parameter):

1. Create a `task` parameter in your data source. ([how to](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005?hl=en)) This can be *text* or *single select*. If it is *single select*, you will have to manually define the values. **Make sure this parameter can be modified by report editors.**
2. In your query, add to the `WHERE` clause:
   `WHERE task = @task`
3. Add the appropriate control in the report and link it to the `task` parameters.

[This post](https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/introducing-bigquery-parameters-data-studio/) has a similar example in the *Creating parameterized custom queries* section.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but need to pass Task in a subquery. The task is not a first-level filter. Somehow I need it to pass it in the subquery. I can pass the date in subquery via `@DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE` but cannot do the same with Task. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, your 3rd step is not working for me. Can you please elaborate on it in more detail? I have to pass **task** in the subquery. I created a custom param task and added task=@task but then it's not working for task control.

Comment: In step 1, please make sure the parameter can be modified by report editors. Then for Step 3, see "Use a control to get input from report viewers" at this url: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, @MinhaZ. Your solution is working for a single select but not working for multi-select. I wrote `Task IN (ARRAY_TO_STRING(@task, ',', 'NULL'))` but it's not working.