# How to add a field as a parameter in Data Studio

Tags: parameters, google-bigquery, looker-studio

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177330/how-can-i-add-query-parameter-to-bigquery-add-connect-it-to-data-studio), someone asked how to add a query parameter to BigQuery and connect it to Data Studio. Someone answered and said to use a custom query and 'add the field as a parameter'. They use the same images and examples that are used in [this Google blog post](https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/introducing-bigquery-parameters-data-studio/) and I cannot figure out how to make a field into a parameter based on either of these sources.

It looks to me like you can only create a list of text values, numbers, or specify a Boolean parameter. Ideally, I don't want to manually create a list of values based on the field since the values in the field might change over time. I want to be able to use these parameters in the Custom Query's WHERE clause so that data is dynamically filtered as the user selects the different parameter options. Using a multi-select option is required, so this would require filling a string array for the parameter, with the default setting to be including all of the possible values (or being able to change `WHERE company IN UNNEST(@company)` to `WHERE company = company`.

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64001501/how-to-pass-data-studio-controls-to-bigquery-custom-query) is pretty much what I'm after, but I cannot figure out how to fill a parameter with dimension values. This looks like it might not be possible, as there are issues in the Issue Tracker that relate to this capability.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to get the logic working for `WHERE company IN UNNEST(@company)` using a manually typed list of values. I think there's a bug currently in DS where the changes won't work properly until you publish the report. But I still have not found a way to fill in the dimension values without manually typing them in, which is going to get very tedious with fields that have >100 options easily